# How do I import "%>%" when writing an R package?

Tags: r, pipe, r-package, magrittr

I'm running into the following error when loading an R package I'm writing.

```
Error in nations %>% rvest::html_nodes(".x") %>% rvest::html_nodes(".y") %>%  : 
  could not find function "%>%"
```

I'm not sure how to import this in my R package. This is how I have my function setup

```
 nations_url_odd<-nations %>%
    rvest::html_nodes('.x') %>%
    rvest::html_nodes('.y') %>%
    rvest::html_nodes('a')
```

Comment: Add `importFrom(magrittr,"%>%")` to your `NAMESPACE` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a `reexports.R` file in your package with the following lines:

```r
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#' @export
magrittr::`%>%`
```

This will make the pipe available to your package and also reexport it to users of your package, so when they load or attach your package the pipe will be available to them (they won’t have to also load magrittr). This can be automated with `usethis::use_pipe()` (see https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/use_pipe.html). As @user2554330 mentions below, this solution depends on the use of [roxygen2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/index.html).

Comment: But only if you use `Roxygen2`.  Not everybody does...

Comment: @user2554330 fair point; I have amended my answer to include your comments.

Answer (score 2):

@Wil gives the best solution if you're a `roxygen2` user.  If not, then as @ArtemSokolov said in a comment, add this line to your `NAMESPACE` file:

```
importFrom(magrittr,"%>%")
```

If you also want users of your package to be able to use the pipe without a `library(magrittr)` call or similar, also add this line to `NAMESPACE`:

```
export("%>%")
```

You'll also need to make sure your `DESCRIPTION` file includes `magrittr` on the `Imports:` line, e.g.

```
Imports: magrittr
```